# How can I display rate constants over the arrows using chemmacros?

Tags: chemmacros

I tried to use

```
\begin{reaction} E + S <=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$] ES <=> EP <=> E + P \end{reaction}
```

but it wouldn't display the subscripts properly. I'm using sharelatex.com but I run MacTeX offline.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect by

> it wouldn't display the subscripts properly

you mean that the underscore is printed instead of interpreted as subscript?

You have two options:

- leave spaces around the math or
- use `\sb` instead of `_`

Since this is unrelated to the `chemmacros` package and its `{reaction}` environment but really is due to the behaviour of `chemformula` I don't use `chemmacros` in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}

% wrong:
\ch{ E + S <=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$] ES <=> EP <=> E + P }

% works:
\ch{ E + S <=>[$k\sb{1}$][$k\sb{-1}$] ES <=> EP <=> E + P }

% works but inserts a space in front of the math:
\ch{ E + S <=>[ $k_1$ ][ $k_{-1}$ ] ES <=> EP <=> E + P }

% works:
\ch[math-space=0pt]{ E + S <=>[ $k_1$ ][ $k_{-1}$ ] ES <=> EP <=> E + P }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just stumbled upon this with the same question… How would I know to use `\sb`? I managed to find some information about the command, but can't find anything that points it out as an alias for `_` (`latexdef -f _` doesn't mention the alias, though `latexdef -f sb` points back to the original definition). Any suggestions here?

Comment: @DustinWheeler It should be mentioned in a comprehensive LaTeX introduction. The LaTeX kernel itself does `\let\sp=^` and `\let\sb=_`

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I should get used to digging into code more often… the idea still doesn't come naturally to me. BTW, your chem packages are fantastic, thanks for the great work!